# jsonschemavalidator.net is failing to match dateTime pattern

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to validate JSON file against this schema including dateTime regex pattern:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/product.schema.json",
  "title": "title",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "entries": {
      "description": "date time entries",
      "type": "array",      
      "contains": {
        "type": "object"
      },
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "dateTime": {
            "description": "UTC timestamp in format \"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD\" according to ISO 8601",
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^(-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(.[0-9]{3})?(?:Z|[+-][01][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])?$"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to validate this JSON file:

```
{
  "description": "date time entries",
  "entries": [
    {
      "dateTime": "2020-10-09T08:48:41.348+02:00"
    },
    {
      "dateTime": "2020-10-09T08:48:52.240+02:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

I get the following error regarding second entry in the array:

**String '2020-10-09T06:48:52.24+00:00' does not match regex pattern '^(-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(.[0-9]{3})?(?:Z|[+-][01][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])?$'.**

Please note, that the validator correctly validated 1st entry: "2020-10-09T08:48:41.348+02:00".
What I noticed is that the problem is with entries containing milliseconds with "0" at the end, like: ".24**0**"

Comment: `2020-10-09T08:48:52.240+02:00` in your data as `2020-10-09T06:48:52.24+00:00` in your error message. This is a "your data is wrong or the regex is wrong" problem. This has nothing to do with JSON Schema or the validation process.

Comment: What exactly do you WANT to happen here? The data is wrong according to the regular expression.

Comment: In fact, I do not understand why the validator refers to: '2020-10-09T06:48:52.24+00:00', while it is in fact: '2020-10-09T08:48:52.240+02:00' in the original JSON. Please note that once I changed to '2020-10-09T08:48:52.241+02:00' (241 milliseconds instead of 240), the validator stops complaining.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are sending that string and not a Java object which gets serialised into a JSON string? I don't think anyone can help unless you provide code which can reproduce this issue. This is still not a JSON Schema issue.

Comment: In order to reproduce, just enter jsonschemavalidator.net site and paste schema and json.

Comment: Then it sounds like a bug. Works as expected using https://jsonschema.dev